# Extract dictionary from python string having word with double quotes inside values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this string which is dynamic and I can't change the values inside it manually.

```
text = """
{
"key1": "this is "value1" right",
"key2": "this is "value2" right"
}
"""
```

I need to extract the dictionary from this, I can't use literal_eval directly because of the quotes in value1 and value2. So, my desired value is:

```
{
"key1": "this is 'value1' right",
"key2": "this is 'value2' right"
}
```

Any solution to it?

Comment: You should fix the source of those values really, get it to give you valid JSON...

Comment: That's like wanting to print 5 with `print(value)` but having `value=2` and not being allowed to change `value`

Comment: If the quoted string can contain unescaped quote characters, how can you know whether a quote character is the end of the string or not. You'll need to define some other criteria to determine where the second string ends.

Comment: Use a regular expression or remove trailing commas (if present), split each line at the first `:` (if any), remove outermost double quotes, replace other double quotes by single ones and add the resulting string pair to a real dict.

Comment: If your data is simple and follows this pattern then the directions from @MichaelButscher will set you on the right path.

Comment: I don't understand why this got so downvoted. It's a perfectly reasonable question. *Should* the JSON data be properly formatted? Yes, of course. But in the real world we can't always control what shitty data we get sent by others, and we need to figure out how to parse it anway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with regex:

Build a regular expression capturing anything consisting of two double-quote-encased sequences that are separated by a colon (with or without a space).

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r'("(.*)": ?"(.*)")')
```

Find all matches and convert to a dict. The nested groupings means we can iterate over each "line" of the input (note that it doesn't care about newlines). Each match returns a tuple of three values: the whole "line", the key, and the value.

```py
d = {item[1]: item[2] for item in r.findall(text)}
```

You can also replace the double-quotes inside the strings with single-quotes:

```py
d = {item[1]: item[2].replace('"', "'") for item in r.findall(text)}
```

The complete program that pretty-prints the terrible string as a properly formatted JSON:

```py
import re
import json

text = """
{
    "test": "test of nested quotes (like "this")",
    "test2": ""test of nested quotes (like "this")"",
    "test3":""test of nested quotes (like "this")"",
    "te:st3":""test of nested quotes (like "this")""
}
"""

r = re.compile(r'("(.*)": ?"(.*)")')
d = {item[1]: item[2].replace('"', "'") for item in r.findall(text)}

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

# Output:
# {
#     "test": "test of nested quotes (like 'this')",
#     "test2": "'test of nested quotes (like 'this')'",
#     "test3": "'test of nested quotes (like 'this')'",
#     "te:st3": "'test of nested quotes (like 'this')'"
# }
```